# How do I stop scrollview from scrolling to the top after a button is clicked?

Tags: android, android-scrollview

I am working on my first app and have it working pretty much as I would like with one small exception. The problem is in the scrollview with a relative layout that contains up to 20 buttons.  When I scroll down and click on a button near the bottom the scrollview it scrolls back to the top after the click.  I want the scrollview to stay where it is after a click.  For example after clicking button 18 I don't want the user to have to scroll back down to the bottom to click button 19. Can someone tell me how to stop the scrollview from automatically scrolling to the top after a click.

```
    <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/timerScrollView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/startStopBtn"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >
        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/runner1Btn"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/startStopBtn"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:background="#101fbd"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:id="@+id/runner1TimeView"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/runner1Btn"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/runner2Btn"
            android:background="#101fbd"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:isScrollContainer="true"
            android:keepScreenOn="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/runner1Btn"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/runner1Btn"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/runner3Btn"
            android:background="#101fbd"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
            android:layout_below="@+id/runner2Btn"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_alignStart="@id/runner1Btn"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/runner4Btn"
            android:background="#101fbd"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/runner3Btn"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
            android:isScrollContainer="false"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_alignStart="@id/runner1Btn"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/runner5Btn"
            android:background="#101fbd"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/runner4Btn"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_alignStart="@id/runner1Btn"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/runner6Btn"
            android:background="#101fbd"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/runner5Btn"
            android:layout_alignStart="@id/runner1Btn"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/runner7Btn"
            android:background="#101fbd"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/runner6Btn"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_alignStart="@id/runner1Btn"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/runner8Btn"
            android:background="#101fbd"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:isScrollContainer="true"
            android:keepScreenOn="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/runner1Btn"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/runner7Btn"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/runner9Btn"
            android:background="#101fbd"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
            android:layout_below="@+id/runner8Btn"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_alignStart="@id/runner1Btn"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/runner10Btn"
            android:background="#101fbd"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/runner9Btn"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
            android:isScrollContainer="false"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_alignStart="@id/runner1Btn"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/runner11Btn"
            android:background="#101fbd"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/runner10Btn"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_alignStart="@id/runner1Btn"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/runner12Btn"
            android:background="#101fbd"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/runner11Btn"
            android:layout_alignStart="@id/runner1Btn"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/runner13Btn"
            android:background="#101fbd"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/runner12Btn"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_alignStart="@id/runner1Btn"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/runner14Btn"
            android:background="#101fbd"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/runner13Btn"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_alignStart="@id/runner1Btn"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/runner15Btn"
            android:background="#101fbd"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:isScrollContainer="true"
            android:keepScreenOn="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/runner1Btn"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/runner14Btn"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/runner16Btn"
            android:background="#101fbd"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
            android:layout_below="@+id/runner15Btn"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_alignStart="@id/runner1Btn"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/runner17Btn"
            android:background="#101fbd"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/runner16Btn"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
            android:isScrollContainer="false"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_alignStart="@id/runner1Btn"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/runner18Btn"
            android:background="#101fbd"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/runner17Btn"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_alignStart="@id/runner1Btn"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/runner19Btn"
            android:background="#101fbd"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/runner18Btn"
            android:layout_alignStart="@id/runner1Btn"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/runner20Btn"
            android:background="#101fbd"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/runner19Btn"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_alignStart="@id/runner1Btn"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:id="@+id/runner2TimeView"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/runner2Btn"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@id/runner1TimeView"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="false" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:id="@+id/runner3TimeView"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/runner3Btn"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@id/runner1TimeView"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:id="@+id/runner4TimeView"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/runner4Btn"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@id/runner1TimeView"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:id="@+id/runner5TimeView"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/runner5Btn"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@id/runner1TimeView"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:id="@+id/runner6TimeView"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/runner6Btn"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@id/runner1TimeView"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:id="@+id/runner7TimeView"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/runner7Btn"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@id/runner1TimeView"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:id="@+id/runner8TimeView"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/runner8Btn"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@id/runner1TimeView"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="false" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:id="@+id/runner9TimeView"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/runner9Btn"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@id/runner1TimeView"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:id="@+id/runner10TimeView"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/runner10Btn"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@id/runner1TimeView"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:id="@+id/runner11TimeView"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/runner11Btn"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@id/runner1TimeView"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:id="@+id/runner12TimeView"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/runner12Btn"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@id/runner1TimeView"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:id="@+id/runner13TimeView"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/runner13Btn"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@id/runner1TimeView"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:id="@+id/runner14TimeView"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/runner14Btn"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@id/runner1TimeView"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:id="@+id/runner15TimeView"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/runner15Btn"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@id/runner1TimeView"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="false" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:id="@+id/runner16TimeView"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/runner16Btn"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@id/runner1TimeView"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:id="@+id/runner17TimeView"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/runner17Btn"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@id/runner1TimeView"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:id="@+id/runner18TimeView"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/runner18Btn"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@id/runner1TimeView"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:id="@+id/runner19TimeView"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/runner19Btn"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@id/runner1TimeView"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:id="@+id/runner20TimeView"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/runner20Btn"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@id/runner1TimeView"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Here is my JAVA code for the OnClickListener for one of the buttons.

```
    runner[18].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (runnerRunning[18]) {
                time[18] = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
                runners.get(18).setTime(formatTime(time[18]));
                runnerTime[18].setText(formatTime(time[18]));
                runnerRunning[18] = false;
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Is there any code that handles the clicks? Could it be causing a refresh of the view?

Comment: you need not to stop it because scrollview should stay in its place. can u post your java code??? may be you are refreshing the view at some point

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  I added the OnClickListener for one of the buttons above.  They are all the same.  Could this be refreshing the view somehow?   It calculates the runners time, saves it in aa array list (runners) and displays it on a textview (runnerTime)

Comment: I wonder whether the setText causes resizing of textview which in turn leads to refresh of layout. Can you try having some long dummy string in the text views initially?

Comment: I'll try something like that Mobile Developer.  The textview is set to wrap content. Maybe if I give it a set size.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone.  Giving the textview a set size  instead of using wrap content worked.